# uploading images in one tab = my website wont open images in another - chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, browser

Sometimes I upload some images (admin area) to my website. About 100 images.
If I open another table (while still uploading) in chrome and go to my website home page, images won't open on chrome. If I open my website in another browser, not on chrome, it works normally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force a cache refresh? You can do that by typing <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: I will try, but I think it wont work because chrome shows the articles normally, but not images... they take infinite time to load, they will only load when I finish uploading imagens in the first tab.